# I have trouble converted ffmpeg command to ffmpeg-python

Tags: python, ffmpeg, ffmpeg-python

I am trying convert from HDR to SDR by using the following ffmpeg command, which works

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov -vf zscale=t=linear:npl=100,format=gbrpf32le,zscale=p=bt709,tonemap=tonemap=hable:desat=0,zscale=t=bt709:m=bt709:r=tv,format=yuv420p -c:v libx264 -crf 0 -preset ultrafast -tune fastdecode output.mp4
```

However, I have trouble converting this in ffmpeg-python format. Could you give me guidance on how to deal with semicolons, equals and weird = = cases?

```
ffmpeg.input("input.mov", r=fps).filter('zscale', t='linear:npl').filter('format', 'gbrpf32le') ...
```

Comment: Remember that the Python `ffmpeg` module just builds up a command line and executes it.  If you have a command line that works, then just use `subprocess.run` to run that command line.

Comment: Looks good so far.  What's the problem exactly?  Is there an error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conversion is quite straightforward:

```
ffmpeg.input('input.mov')\
    .video.filter('zscale', t='linear', npl=100)\
    .filter('format', pix_fmts='gbrpf32le')\
    .filter('zscale', p='bt709')\
    .filter('tonemap', tonemap='hable', desat=0)\
    .filter('zscale', t='bt709', m='bt709', r='tv')\
    .filter('format', pix_fmts='yuv420p')\
    .output('output.mp4', vcodec='libx264', crf=0, preset='ultrafast', tune='fastdecode')\
    .run()
```

---

- Arguments of `ffmpeg.input(...)` begins with input file name followed by input arguments.
- `.video` followed by `.filter(...).filter(...).filter(...)` applies chain of video filters.
- `filter(...)` begins with filter name followed by filter parameters as arguments.
  The syntax is <param_name0>=param_value0, <param_name1>=param_value1...
- output(...) begins with output file name followed by output arguments.

The only caveat is the `format` filter.
The parameter name of `format` filter is `pix_fmts` (we usually skip it).
One way for getting the parameter name is using FFmpeg help (in command line):

`ffmpeg -h filter=format`

Output:

```
Filter format
  Convert the input video to one of the specified pixel formats.
    Inputs:
       #0: default (video)
    Outputs:
       #0: default (video)
(no)format AVOptions:
   pix_fmts          <string>     ..FV....... A '|'-separated list of pixel formats
```

Here we can see that the parameter name is `pix_fmts`.

---

When using ffmpeg-python, it is recommended to add `.overwrite_output()` (equivalent to `-y` argument).

For testing it is recommended to add `.global_args('-report')` for creating a log file (remove `.global_args('-report')` after finish testing).

```
ffmpeg.input('input.mov')\
    .video.filter('zscale', t='linear', npl=100)\
    .filter('format', pix_fmts='gbrpf32le')\
    .filter('zscale', p='bt709')\
    .filter('tonemap', tonemap='hable', desat=0)\
    .filter('zscale', t='bt709', m='bt709', r='tv')\
    .filter('format', pix_fmts='yuv420p')\
    .output('output.mp4', vcodec='libx264', crf=0, preset='ultrafast', tune='fastdecode')\
    .global_args('-report').overwrite_output().run()
```

The log shows us the actual FFmpeg command:

`ffmpeg -i input.mov -filter_complex "[0:v]zscale=npl=100:t=linear[s0];[s0]format=pix_fmts=gbrpf32le[s1];[s1]zscale=p=bt709[s2];[s2]tonemap=desat=0:tonemap=hable[s3];[s3]zscale=m=bt709:r=tv:t=bt709[s4];[s4]format=pix_fmts=yuv420p[s5]" -map "[s5]" -crf 0 -preset ultrafast -tune fastdecode -vcodec libx264 output.mp4 -report -y`

As you can see, ffmpeg-python uses `-filter_complex` instead of `-vf`, and uses temporary naming as `[s0]`, `[s1]`, `[s2]`...
The result is equivalent to your original command.